# How to use getOrElse with Map and compare value in scala

Tags: scala

I have parsed JSON to a Map[String , Any].In JSON I have a hasHeader optional field.

```
{
hasHeader : "Y"  (optional member)

}
```

I want to check

```
If(jsonMap.get("hasHeader") <=> "Y")
  doSome()
else
  Nothing
```

As hadHeader is optional it is safe to use getOrElse but how do I use getOrElse and compare value with "Y" in scala.

One way I can think of is:

```
 if(!jsonMap.get("hasHeader").isEmpty) {
          val hasHeaderVal = jsonMap.get("hasHeader")

         if( hasHeaderVal.equals("Y")){
               doSomething()
           }
      }
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

```
jsonMap.get("hasHeader").map(_ == "Y").getOrElse(false)
```

The way `.map` works for `Option`s is that it only applies the given function if the value is a `Some` (otherwise the `None` just passes through). Then, `.getOrElse` gets the value if the `Option` it is called on is a `Some` but otherwise returns its first argument (sort of a default backup).

Comment: for me, if the Option it is called on a Some I get back true, not the value from the map. Is there a way to refactor this to return the value from the map, e.g. in this case "Y"?

Comment: @DarceyBM isn't that just directly `jsonMap.get("hasHeader")`? What would you expect the function to return if the value is not in the map?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern-matching on the option to achieve the compare-action.

Here I am assuming that your `doSomething` has a return type of `Unit`.

```
 jsonMap.get("hasHeader") match {
   case Some("Y") => doSomething()
   case _ => 
 }
```

In case your `doSomething` returns something (lets assume an `Int`) then,

```
def doSomething(): Int = 5

// you can get option of your requirement like this

val intOption = jsonMap.get("hasHeader") match {
  case Some("Y") => Option(doSomething())
  case _ => None
}

// or
val intOption = jsonMap.get("hasHeader")
  .filter(_.equals("Y"))
  .map(s => doSomething())

// or if you do not want an option and have a fallback value 10
val int = jsonMap.get("hasHeader")
  .filter(_.equals("Y"))
  .map(s => doSomething())
  .getOrElse(10)
```